# How to call a function from another class with its context (android, java)

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-adapter, android-context

I'm trying to reload a viewPager whenever the user pushes a button inside an Item from the viewPager. The relevant classes for this case are `SetupActivity` and `Adapter`. In the activity class I've already made the two functions to reload the viewPager:

```
public void deleteSession(String title) {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        ((DatabaseHelper) dbHelper).deleteRow(title);
    }
```

and

```
public void refreshAdapter () {

        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this); 
        Cursor dataCursor = ((DatabaseHelper) dbHelper).getData();
        models = new ArrayList<>(); 

        while (dataCursor.moveToNext()) { 
            models.add(new Model(
                    dataCursor.getString(1),
                    dataCursor.getInt(2),
                    dataCursor.getInt(3),
                    dataCursor.getInt(4)
            ));
        }
        adapter = new Adapter(models, this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
    }
```

So basically, `deleteSession()` deletes a specific item from a database. `refreshAdapter()` reads the updated data from the database and sets a new adapter to the viewPager.
These functions are working fine, if I call them from an OnClick event in the `SetupActivity` class. However, if I try to call them from an OnClick event in the `Adapter` class, the app crashes with the following errors:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getDatabasePath(ContextWrapper.java:327)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:352)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:322)
        at com.example.android.slink.DatabaseHelper.getData(DatabaseHelper.java:69)
        at com.example.android.slink.SetupActivity.refreshAdapter(SetupActivity.java:436)
        at com.example.android.slink.Adapter$3.onClick(Adapter.java:111)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6669)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6638)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:789)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26145)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Here's my `SetupActiviy` class (reduced to the relevant parts):

```
package com.example.android.slink;

public class SetupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    ViewPager viewPager;
    Adapter adapter;
    static ArrayList<Model> models;

    public void deleteSession(String title) {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        ((DatabaseHelper) dbHelper).deleteRow(title);
    }

    public void refreshAdapter () {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        Cursor dataCursor = ((DatabaseHelper) dbHelper).getData();
        models = new ArrayList<>();
        models.add(new Model("", 0,0,0));
        while (dataCursor.moveToNext()) {
            models.add(new Model(
                    dataCursor.getString(1),
                    dataCursor.getInt(2),
                    dataCursor.getInt(3),
                    dataCursor.getInt(4)
            ));
        }
        adapter = new Adapter(models, this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup);

        editTextScreenTitle = findViewById(R.id.editTextScreenTitle);
        relativeLayoutCard = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutCard);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        Cursor dataCursor = ((DatabaseHelper) dbHelper).getData();

        models = new ArrayList<>();
        models.add(new Model("", 0,0,0));
        while (dataCursor.moveToNext()) {
            models.add(new Model(
                    dataCursor.getString(1),
                    dataCursor.getInt(2),
                    dataCursor.getInt(3),
                    dataCursor.getInt(4)
            ));
        }
        adapter = new Adapter(models, this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Here's my `Adapter` class (also reduced to the relevant parts):

```
package com.example.android.slink;

public class Adapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private List<Model> models;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;

    SetupActivity setupActivity = new SetupActivity();

    public Adapter(List<Model> models, Context context) {
        this.models = models;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, container, false);

        TextView buttonDeleteCard = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDeleteCard);

        buttonDeleteCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setupActivity.deleteSession([...some title...]);
                setupActivity.refreshAdapter();
            }
        });

        container.addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    }
}
```

I think it has something to do whith the context.
Do I have to pass the context from `SetupActiity` to the `Adapter` class and if so, how do I do that?
Or is it not possible and I need to catch the OnClick event in the `Adapter` class from in the `SetupActivity` class?
I'm new to java programming and would be very grateful if any of you could help me, solve this problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `Adapter` like this:

```
public class Adapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private List<Model> models;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;

    private SetupActivity setupActivity;

    public Adapter(List<Model> models, Context context) {
        this.models = models;
        this.context = context;
        setupActivity = (SetupActivity) context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, container, false);

        TextView buttonDeleteCard = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDeleteCard);

        buttonDeleteCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setupActivity.deleteSession([...some title...]);
                setupActivity.refreshAdapter();
            }
        });

        container.addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**Why the error?**

You pass the `Context` from `SetupActivity` to your `Adapter`, you save that reference in the field (`context`) but you mistakenly created a new instance of `SetupActivity`.

That's why you got the `NullPointerException`. The activity is your `Context`. It inherits from it. So just cast it in your constructor and use it later.

Comment: I'm glad that I did!